# PC Lint info 825 suppress is not working using fallthrough comment

Tags: c, pc-lint

I have a code where am getting `PC Lint info 825`, even though I'm using `/* fallthrough */` comment. Tell me if any of my usage is wrong.

Example code:

```
case 1:

case 2:

case 3:
{
    statement;
}

/* fallthrough */

case 4:
{
statement 1;
statement 2;
break;
}

default:
break;
```

Comment: The solution: never use the icky fall-through feature, it is almost certainly the wrong solution and a strong indication of bad program design.

Comment: Than how to suppress above info

Comment: By writing proper code that doesn't fall through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong comment content. Try:

```
//lint -fallthrough
```

See [the huge text file](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pub/msg.txt) for details.

Comment: it works ,but as above in the comment is it usage of this is bad